# Impedir acesso direto aos vídeos do wordpress (prevent direct access files)

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Possuo uma aplicação de learning baseada em wordpress, e possuo ainda diversas vídeo aulas no diretório `public_html/wp-content/uploads/...`

Gostaria de impedir o acesso direto a esses vídeos, uma vez que que é necessário realizar a aquisição do curso para poder assisti-los.

Ao estudar a questão deparei-me com as seguintes proposições de solução para este problema:

**Solução 1**: Bloquear requisições vindas da WEB, utilizado um arquivo `.htaccess`, aos meus arquivos de vídeo (.mp4) e servi-los ao cliente com PHP, através da função [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php). Deste modo eu poderia verificar se o usuário pode acessar o arquivo, antes de servi-lo. Esta solução é funcional, mas não me agradou, pois acredito que o consumo de recursos do servidor será muito alto, já que o PHP estará lendo/processando os arquivos.

Neste caso adicionaria um arquivo `.htaccess` em `wp-content/uploads/` com a seguinte diretivas:

```
     Rewriterule \.mp4$ dl-file.php [L]
```

E usaria um script (`dl-file.php`) análogo a este para servir o arquivo de vídeo :

```
 /*
 * dl-file.php
 *
 * Protect uploaded files with login.
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37144/protect-wordpress-uploads-if-user-is-not-logged-in
 *
 * @author hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>
 * @license GPL-3.0+
 * @registry SPDX
 */

require_once('wp-load.php');

is_user_logged_in() ||  auth_redirect();

list($basedir) = array_values(array_intersect_key(wp_upload_dir(), array('basedir' => 1)))+array(NULL);

$file =  rtrim($basedir,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])?$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');
if (!$basedir || !is_file($file)) {
    status_header(404);
    die('404 &#8212; File not found.');
}

$mime = wp_check_filetype($file);
if( false === $mime[ 'type' ] && function_exists( 'mime_content_type' ) )
    $mime[ 'type' ] = mime_content_type( $file );

if( $mime[ 'type' ] )
    $mimetype = $mime[ 'type' ];
else
    $mimetype = 'image/' . substr( $file, strrpos( $file, '.' ) + 1 );

header( 'Content-Type: ' . $mimetype ); // always send this
if ( false === strpos( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS' ) )
    header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );

$last_modified = gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime( $file ) );
$etag = '"' . md5( $last_modified ) . '"';
header( "Last-Modified: $last_modified GMT" );
header( 'ETag: ' . $etag );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 100000000 ) . ' GMT' );

// Support for Conditional GET
$client_etag = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) ? stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) : false;

if( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] ) )
    $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] = false;

$client_last_modified = trim( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] );
// If string is empty, return 0. If not, attempt to parse into a timestamp
$client_modified_timestamp = $client_last_modified ? strtotime( $client_last_modified ) : 0;

// Make a timestamp for our most recent modification...
$modified_timestamp = strtotime($last_modified);

if ( ( $client_last_modified && $client_etag )
    ? ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) && ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    : ( ( $client_modified_timestamp >= $modified_timestamp) || ( $client_etag == $etag ) )
    ) {
    status_header( 304 );
    exit;
}

// If we made it this far, just serve the file
readfile( $file );
```

Neste caso os arquivos de vídeo não estariam fora de `public_html`, uma vez que eu ainda precisaria avaliar as consequências disso, para minha aplicação Wordpress, e ainda os impactos sob alguns utilitários que utilizo, baseados na API interna do [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/).

**Solução 2**: Utilizar um módulo do apache chamado [`mod_xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) para servir o arquivo, após verificar, com PHP, se o usuário pode ou não obter acesso àquele vídeo. `mod_xsendfile` é um módulo não oficial, de um terceiro, e a última atualização data de 2012. Devido a estes fatores, somado ao fato do projeto não possuir uma comunidade ativa, optei por não utilizar esta solução.

**Solução 3**: Impedir o acesso direto através de um arquivo `.htacess` realizando a checagem do header `%{HTTP_REFERER}`. Este não é um modo confiável, uma vez que devo permitir, por questões de usabilidade, o acesso quando `%{HTTP_REFERER}` também for vazio, ou seja, basta um cliente modificar `%{HTTP_REFERER}` para ter acesso às vídeo aulas (.mp4) privadas. Caso o valor de `%{HTTP_REFERER}` fosse confiável, em 100% das vezes, esta seria uma boa solução, pois a entrega do arquivo de vídeo estaria condicionada à minha aplicação, que decide se o usuário deve ou não acessar a aula.

**Solução 4:** Utilizar um plugin denominado [Prevent Direct Access](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-direct-access/)
[image: imagem do cabeçalho do plugin no repositório oficial do worpress]
Para entregar o arquivo ao usuário o plugin utiliza-se de um script muito semelhante ao exibido na **solução 1**, o que também o tornou inviável, além do custo da licença ser alto. Mas em linhas gerais é uma boa solução quando os arquivos a serem disponibilizados não são muito grandes.

**Solução 5**: Por fim eu imaginei uma possível solução para meu problema, mas me falta, ainda, o conhecimento necessário para verificar sua aplicabilidade, segue:

Sempre que um usuário realizar uma requisição direta a um arquivo de vídeo eu realizo a checagem de uma flag através de um arquivo `.htaccess`. Quanto a esta flag eu ainda não sei ao certo o que ela pode ser, um parâmetro `get`, ou então uma variável de ambiente do apache, ou ainda um header.

Se esta flag possuir um dado valor eu realizo o envio do arquivo, ou então caso ela possua um outro valor, diferente do necessário para que o arquivo seja enviado, o mesmo não é enviado ao usuário. Por fim se esta flag não existir, no momento da checagem, eu reescrevo a URL com uma diretiva `RewriteRule` que apontará a um script PHP.

Este script verifica se o usuário pode ou não acessar o arquivo de vídeo (verifica se esta logado e se realizou a compra do curso, basicamente) e então seta a respectiva flag, e faz uma nova requisição ao arquivo de vídeo, o que fará com que o `.htaccess` executado anteriormente seja executado novamente, porém agora a flag existe, pois foi definida no script. Com isso o arquivo `.htaccess` encontrará a flag definida, e em função do valor decide por entregar ou não o arquivo solicitado ao usuário. Após enviar a resposta a flag é então destruída.

Como mencionei, não sei dizer se isto é possível, e quais estruturas utilizar. Trata-se de uma suposta solução, que preciso verificar se é possível. Caso não seja como eu poderia fazer para impedir o acesso direto aos vídeos, lembrando de considerar as soluções que já encontrei e descartei anteriormente.

Comment: coloca .htaccess com: deny from all

Comment: Mas neste caso como eu serviria ao usuário os vídeos? Teria de realizar a leitura dos mesmos com PHP?

Comment: Sobre o 2, apesar de não ser algo muito atualizado (afinal, é bem  simples, nao tem o que atualizar), não tem problema nenhum usar X-SendFile no Apache atualmente. Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada? Inclusive, tem disponível pronto para muitas distros. Ex: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/mod_xsendfile-0.12-10.el7.x86_64.rpm.html - O único caminho que vejo para o seu caso é realmente permitir o acesso após login, seja por X-SendFile ou mesmo por um PHP servindo arquivo gravado fora da raiz do site (que é o normal e simples de se fazer nesses casos).

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo @Bacco. Verifiquei a solução 1, parcialmente, e ela se mostrou funcional, apesar de, teoricamente, aparentar ser muito custosa aos meus olhos. Por que você a considera ineficaz ? Quanto ao uso do `X-SendFile`, após pesquisas, deparei-me com algumas opiniões contrárias ao seu uso ( [esta](https://serverfault.com/a/879140) por exemplo) e apesar de, teoricamente ser a solução ideal para mim isto me fez recuar um pouco. Você já utilizou este módulo? Quanto a "um PHP servindo arquivo gravado fora da raiz do site" neste caso eu teria de processar o arquivo, o que desejo evitar.

Comment: Uso X-SendFile constantemente para aliviar o trabalho do PHP, mas lembre-se que se não quiser usar, tem o `readfile();` do próprio PHP, que pode pegar arquivos fora da raiz sem problema (que é parcialmente seu 1). Só dou preferência ao módulo justamente para não ter o PHP processando o stream à toa se posso deixar para o Apache. Sobre o link, é uma opinião, de uma pessoa, que até pode ser válida, mas tem que relativizar um bocado.

Comment: Sobre o 1, falei em relação ao htaccess, nao ao readfile() - no sentido de que é melhor colocar os arquivos fora da raiz, em vez de ter que criar bloqueios. Não entendi o que quis dizer com "ter que processar os arquivos" nesse contexto.

Comment: @Bacco, entendi. Eu irei me voltar para o estudo do ´mod_xsendfile´, baseado nas suas colocações. Vou realizar alguns testes para verificar sua aplicabilidade, no meu caso. Se puder formalizar suas afirmações como uma resposta à pergunta principal eu poderei classifica-la, posteriormente, e usa-la no edit da questão. Obrigado por sua ajuda.

Comment: @AllanDantas se preferir manter o readfile, desde que o servidor tenha folga de recursos, não vejo problema, mas o fundamental seja com sendfile ou readfile, é o arquivo estar fora da raiz em vez de apenas bloqueado

Comment: @Bacco, o Wordpress mantém suas mídias dentro de um diretório em `public_html`, teria de analisar as implicações desta mudança. A solução que tenho em mente é utilizar `FilesMatch` para identificar quando esta sendo realizada uma solicitação a um arquivo `.mp4` e então transferir a responsabilidade de resposta a um script PHP, que enviaria o arquivo com `X-Sendfile`. O que pensa a respeito ?

Comment: Continuo pensando o mesmo, que é melhor tirar da raiz

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100433/discussion-between-allan-dantas-and-bacco).

Answer (score 2):

Coloque os arquivos que você deseja proteger em um subdiretório do diretório em que seu código está sendo executado:

> www.foo.com/player.html
>   www.foo.com/videos/video.mp4

Salve um arquivo nesse subdiretório chamado ".htaccess" e adicione as linhas abaixo:

> www.foo.com/videos/.htaccess

**Conteúdo do .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://foo.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.foo.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]
```

Agora, o link de origem será falso, mas ainda precisamos garantir que qualquer usuário que esteja tentando fazer o download do arquivo não possa receber diretamente o arquivo.

Para uma solução mais completa, coloque seu vídeo com uma tela falsa (ou tela em html) e nunca vincule diretamente ao vídeo. Para desabilitar o botão direito do mouse adicione ao seu HTML:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

**O resultado:**

`www.foo.com/player.html` reproduzirá o vídeo corretamente, mas se você visitar `www.foo.com/videos/video.mp4` receberá uma mensagem de erro:

> Error Code 403: FORBIDDEN

**OBS: Isso funcionará para download direto, cURL, hotlinking, etc.**

Para dificultar ainda mais, você pode mandar uma requisição para o servidor através de um hash md5 temporário, e retornar seu vídeo, através desta instância temporária, dessa maneira não terá um caminho completo do vídeo dentro da sua tela falsa quando expirar esse hash.

Exemplo arquivo (load_video.php):

```
//digamos que você tem isso no banco de dados
$videos = [
 ['directory' => 'videos','file' => 'video_nome_1', 'type' => 'mp4', 'id' => 1],
 ['directory' => 'videos','file' => 'video_nome_2', 'type' => 'mp4', 'id' => 2]
 ['directory' => 'videos','file' => 'video_nome_3', 'type' => 'mp4', 'id' => 3]
];

$data_list_videos = [];

foreach($videos as $k => $video) {
    $data_list_videos[md5($video['id']. range('a', 'd'))] = $video;
}

if($_POST) {
   $validate = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();  
   $video = $data_list_videos[$_POST['video']];
   return json_encode([
     'status' => true,
     'video' => base64_encode($video),
     'validate' => $validate
   ]); 
}
```

Na sua view você poderia chamar algo assim com ID 2 por exemplo, e setar o caminho da vídeo no seu elemento `#leitor`, no caso estou usando a [biblioteca jquery](https://jquery.com/) para fazer um post:

```
<script>
     <?php $id = md5(2 . range('a', 'd')); ?>

            $.post('/load_video.php?video=<?php echo $id?>',function(rtn) {
                var data = JSON.parse(rtn);
                  if(data.status && (<?php echo (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();?> == data.validate)) {

                   var result = data.video;
                   var data_video = window.atob(result);
                  var srcVideo = [
                       '/',
                       data_video.directory,
                       '/',
                       data_video.file,
                       '.',
                       data_video.type,
                       '?',
                       validate=data.validate
                  ];
             var leitor = document.querySelector('#leitor');
             $.get('/leitor.php?video='+window.btoa(srcVideo.join(''))+'&validate='+data.validate, function(srcVideo) { 
                   leitor.src = JSON.parse(srcVideo).src;
                   leitor.setAttribute('type', 'video/'+data_video.type);
             });

       }
 });
</script>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source id="leitor">
    </video>
```

No arquivo de vídeo, pode ser um `leitor.php` você carrega um leitor de video ele retorna a url:

`/leitor.php?validate=1572363160&video=L3ZpZGVvL3ZpZGVvX25vbWVfMi5tcDQ=`

```
   if ($_GET['validate'] == (new DateTime())->getTimestamp()) {
       echo json_decode(['src' => base64_decode($_GET['video'])]);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado por seu tempo Ivan. 
Um usuário não conseguiria alterar `%{HTTP_REFERER}` ?
Há aplicativos de proxy que enviam `%{HTTP_REFERER}` vazio, deste modo um usuário que comprou o curso, mas possui um destes aplicativos rodando em sua máquina não teria problemas ao acessar o vídeo ?

Comment: Quanto ao uso da hash, particularmente, não consigo visualizar outro modo de enviar o arquivo ao usuário, após resolve-la, se não através do PHP. Estou equivocado ?

Comment: @AllanDantas qualquer curioso altera o REFERER sem problema nenhum. Em geral, REFERER não protege nada importante. O máximo que dá pra evitar é hotlinks onde o "espertinho" não tem controle sobre o browser de terceiros, mas não protege conteúdo. Exemplo de uso válido do REFERER: minimizar consumo de banda indevido em larga escala (vc permite só em branco ou igual o do site, e descarta sites de terceiros). Exemplo de uso inválido é o seu caso, onde o atacante tem controle do processo de download.

Comment: @AllanDantas, você também pode ao invés de passar o arquivo de vídeo, passar o hash mesmo, e no servidor resolver trazendo em formato de vídeo... você pode retornar o arquivo mesmo, binário...

Comment: O navegador compara o timestamp obtido em `view.php` com o obtido em `load_video.php`. Desculpe a ignorância, mas o tempo decorrido entre a obtenção do timestamp em `view.php` e a obtenção do timestamp obtido em `load.php` é inferior a um segundo ?

Comment: Tem que encontrar uma maneira assíncrona de fazer isso, mas é só uma ideia para ajudar vc a pensar numa estratégia para o seu problema...

Comment: @IvanFerrer, imaginei. Pensei em armazenar um token em `$_SESSION` e substitui-lo a cada vez que `leitor.php` concluir seu trabalho. No caso do seu exemplo, quando faz um `get` para  `leitor.php` o usuário poderia visualizar o valor da var `video` (`&video=L3ZpZGVvL3ZpZGVvX25vbWVfMi5tcDQ=`) ?

Comment: Há outras maneiras de criptografar isso..., usando `password_hash()` ou `openssl_encrypt()`, por exemplo, [veja um como usar aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string/).

Comment: Fiz um [exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/8FR8z0) para você ver como fazer isso.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, obrigado por seu tempo. Penso que em algum momento o navegador deverá receber o URL descriptografado para que ele possa realizar a requisição ao vídeo. No caso quem enviaria a URL descriptografada ao navegador seria `leitor.php`. Estou correto?

Comment: Sim, a URL tem que ser recebida descriptografada para poder ser reconhecida, pelo leitor, mas não necessariamente exposta... através de um link visualmente falando, apenas como ponteiro, você pode receber um arquivo php que retornará como se a saída do endereço do vídeo fosse ele mesmo... o vídeo pode ser renderizado através da requisição e não do seu caminho exato, e esse arquivo de video, pode ser um leitor de video, e não o vídeo em si... um vídeo dentro de outro... [veja esse link](https://blog.weckx.net/streaming-video-php/)